# Microsoft Intune - install behavior disabled

Tags: installation, windows-installer, intune, orca

I've packaged (and deployed as System user) several applications before using the IntuneWinAppUtil.exe, but something with a certain msi causes the Intune "Install behavior" to be set as "User" and disabled:
[image: intune install behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj4RO.png)

I need this MSI to be installed as System but I have no clue what could be causing it to default as "User" and unchangeable. I tried opening the MSI with Orca, but I couldn't get any further with investigating what could be causing this.

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this before. If you've wrapped a MSI installer, it is only available to be installed via User. This is because the setup file you have is set to an MSI file. If you want, you can point the setup file to a bat/cmd file to bypass it.

Comment: Thanks mate. I ended up creating one install.cmd to wrap this installation and this strategy has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I just ran into this same issue. I had an MSI that would only resolve to user when deploying through Windows app (Win32) option in Intune when I needed it to deploy as device. In this case I found the .exe for the software from the vendor and just wrapped it into a .intunewin  via the IntunewinAppUtil.exe that you can get from Microsoft here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/apps-win32-prepare

I was then able to apply the same MSI install command line to deploy it and set my detection method as well.